# How do I set git origin in sub-folders?

Tags: git, directory

Preliminary info;

- I am using macOS.
- I have a folder named "projects" in which I store all my git repositories. (If this is not logical, please let me know by explaining why. It would help me improve).

What I did;

In the "projects" folder there were 2 already existing projects.

- From my browser I went to GitHub and manually created a new repository.
- Copied clone-url
- Opened terminal and navigated to my "projects" folder
- Created a new file named "x", same name as the newly created repository.

Now here comes the problem.

- While my current working directory was "projects", I typed:

  git remote set-url "clone-url of the new repository"

Now when I type `git status`, the other two repository files that are in "projects" folder are also counted as changes. (Not surprisingly) I believe I should have gone into the "x" file and set the remote origin in that file. (Also if you think there is a mistake in my thinking at this part, please let me know.)

My question is: how do I not see the other 2 repositories' files as "changes to be committed" while I am solely working on the "x" file?

Thank you

Comment: It seems `projects` is a git repository and `projects/foo` and `projects/bar` are also git repositories. This way, you have nested repositories. Do you really want nested repositories?

Comment: Just use a directory per project, naming a file as a repository is weird

Comment: I don't want nested repositories. My initial goal was to have a folder which contained all my repos. But accidentally, initialized that folder as a repo too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To amplify what [Ôrel said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446248/how-do-i-set-git-origin-in-sub-folders#comment112193834_63446248), you should have a *directory* (or folder, if you prefer that term) per project.  You can store all of these in a directory / folder named `projects`, if you like.

Supposing that your two projects are `https://github.com/kutay/proj1` and `https://github.com/kutay/proj2`, you would, on your Mac, starting in your home directory:

```
mac:~$ mkdir projects          # you already did this
mac:~$ cd projects
mac:~/projects$ git clone https://github.com/kutay/proj1
[Git messages happen here]
mac:~/projects$ git clone https://github.com/kutay/proj2
[Git messages happen here as well]
```

The result would be that you now have `projects/proj1` and `projects/proj2` in your home directory, or equivalently, `proj1` and `proj2` in your `projects` directory.  Use `cd` to enter the directory in which you want to do some work, and from there, run `git status` and other Git commands.

#### Important note about how Git projects are laid out

When you're working in a project, you must `cd` into the top level of what Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  For instance: `cd ~/projects/proj1` would get you into the `proj1` work-tree.

At the top level of each work-tree, Git's private files are within a `.git` directory.  That is, there is now a `~/projects/proj1/.git` directory (or folder) in which Git keeps *its* files.  You can, if you like, look at these files (and sub-directories), but in general you should never modify any of these directly.

What Git actually stores, and transfers to and from GitHub, are *commits*.  Each commit stored *every file that Git knows about*, as a full snapshot.  The `git checkout` (or `git switch`) operation tells Git to *copy the files out of a snapshot*.  The files stored in a snapshot are read-only: neither you nor Git can change them.  They're also in a special, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format, so that only Git can *read* them.

The work you do happens in your working tree: here, there are files (and directories / folders) that are stored in ordinary everyday format.  These files are *not actually in the repository*.  The repository files are in that `.git` sub-directory.  Git merely *copies its saved files out to your work-tree* when you ask it to do so.

In other words, there are, at all times, at least two copies of each file: the one in the *current commit*, that you selected with `git checkout` or `git switch`, and the one in your work-tree that you can read and write.  The current commit copy *cannot be changed*.  That's OK!  What you will do, rather than change the files in a commit, is make a *new commit*.

To build a new commit, you will, in general, modify (and/or create) files in your work-tree.  You might think this would be enough, but it's not: Git doesn't make *new* commits from these files!  Instead, Git makes new commits from a *third copy* of each file.  This third copy is in the special, Git-only, de-duplicated format (so most of the time it's not actually a copy at all).

This third copy of each file lives in what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or (rarely these days) the *cache*.  The name "index" is not very good.  Unfortunately it's sort of the main name.  "Staging area" covers how you *use* it, and is better, but isn't really complete, so I mostly use the word "index" here.

To tell Git to update (or create) this third copy in Git's index, you use `git add`.  Run `git add` and tell it the name(s) of some work-tree file(s), and Git will make sure that its index copy of that file matches your work-tree copy.  If you give `git add` an entire directory name like `.` or `subdir`, it will make Git's index contain and match all the files within that directory.

These index copies of each file—in Git's special, read-only, compressed, and de-duplicated format—are the files that Git knows about.  When you run `git commit`, Git will make a new commit with *these* copies of the file.  Since they're already in the Git format, `git commit` can be very quick.  Note that the files in the index have long names with embedded (forward) slashes, like `path/to/file.ext`.  Git's index *cannot* contain a lone folder name, and for this reason, Git commits cannot contain directories.  Commits only contain *files* (well, that and commit metadata, which we haven't covered here).

The remaining things to know ... well, there are a lot of them.  Let's just touch on a few:

- Each Git is stand-alone.  In general (there are some exceptions), *every* Git repository has a copy of *every commit*.
- Every Git repository also has its own private branch names.  What you share between Git repositories are the *commits*.
- To connect two Git repositories, you use `git push` and `git fetch`.

  - The `git push` operation starts with your repository, where you expect to have something that *they* don't have, and you'll give them new commits and then ask them to update some of their branch names.
  - The `git fetch` operation starts with your repository, where you expect that they may have something that you don't, yet.  You connect to them, have your Git ask their Git about *their* branches and commits, and then your Git asks for any commits *they* have, that *you* don't.

  So, after running both operations, both Gits will generally have all the same commits.  You don't have to do both if you're pretty sure that you're already mostly in sync: you only need to `fetch` if you think they have new stuff that you want, and you only need to `push` if you want to give them new stuff.
- *Branch names* are important because they let you *find* commits.  But it's actually the *commits themselves* that matter.  Branch names only matter in terms of *finding* commits.

So, the things to remember are:

- Git is about *commits*.
- Commits contain snapshots (of all files), plus some metadata (that we haven't really talked about).
- Commits are numbered (we haven't talked about this at all), but in a weird way so that the numbers look random.  These are Git's *hash IDs*.  They get abbreviated a lot, to look like `a1c9f33d` and the like.  All Gits everywhere agree about the hash IDs, which is one of the key sources of the magic that makes Git work.
- Branch *names* remember commit hash IDs for you (because otherwise it's impossible!).
- The `git status` command, which we haven't talked about at all, is extremely useful.
- You do your work in your *work-tree* or *working tree*, where you have files you can see and work with.  But these files aren't actually *in* Git.
- You use `git commit` to make new commits, but this doesn't actually use your work-tree files, so you have to use `git add` a lot.
- The essence of a repository is that it contains commits (and other internal Git objects), as a sort of big database of all-commits-ever.  You use `git fetch` to get new commits into your Git.  It also contains some names, such as branch names, to help *find* these commits.
- The repository itself is the `.git` directory.  Inside this repository, the files are in a special Git-only format, contained inside commits (also stored in the Git-only format).  Git's index is also inside this `.git` directory, along with the two databases: the big one of Git objects (including commits), and the one of names (including branch names) that map to commit object IDs (hash IDs).